# baxter sim_kinematics dies (both left and right) with error -11

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running baxter simulation via gazebo using their simulator. But I get following errors while doing a roslaunch.

error 1:

```
[baxter_emulator-8] process has died [pid 8399, exit code -11, cmd /home/mjm/catkin_workspaces/baxter_ws/devel/lib/baxter_sim_hardware/baxter_emulator /home/mjm/catkin_workspaces/baxter_ws/src/src/baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_hardware/images/researchsdk.png __name:=baxter_emulator __log:=/home/mjm/.ros/log/edd5c38c-9c62-11e6-9b5e-14109fd8a0ab/baxter_emulator-8.log].
log file: /home/mjm/.ros/log/edd5c38c-9c62-11e6-9b5e-14109fd8a0ab/baxter_emulator-8*.log
```

A solution to the above problem was found in this [link.](https://groups.google.com/a/rethinkrobotics.com/forum/#!msg/brr-users/2YNo9mJyMQQ/Re122iKJAQAJ)

error 2:

```
 [baxter_sim_kinematics_left-6] process has died [pid 8381, exit code -11, cmd /home/mjm/catkin_workspaces/baxter_ws/devel/lib/baxter_sim_kinematics/kinematics left __name:=baxter_sim_kinematics_left __log:=/home/mjm/.ros/log/edd5c38c-9c62-11e6-9b5e-14109fd8a0ab/baxter_sim_kinematics_left-6.log].
    log file: /home/mjm/.ros/log/edd5c38c-9c62-11e6-9b5e-14109fd8a0ab/baxter_sim_kinematics_left-6*.log
    [baxter_sim_kinematics_right-7] process has died [pid 8391, exit code -11, cmd /home/mjm/catkin_workspaces/baxter_ws/devel/lib/baxter_sim_kinematics/kinematics right __name:=baxter_sim_kinematics_right __log:=/home/mjm/.ros/log/edd5c38c-9c62-11e6-9b5e-14109fd8a0ab/baxter_sim_kinematics_right-7.log].
    log file: /home/mjm/.ros/log/edd5c38c-9c62-11e6-9b5e-14109fd8a0ab/baxter_sim_kinematics_right-7*.log
```

Strangeness of the error:

We have two PC's having same hardware, same OS (Ubuntu 14.04) and ROS(indigo) and same baxter files (same git versions). In one PC is works perfectly fine, while the other it does not. Another problem is, it doesn't write any log file as shown in the error description. It only writes logs of those files that was successfully loaded.

Could any one please suggest anything or give a guidance on how to debug it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246605/baxter-sim_kinematics-dies-(both-left-and-right)-with-error--11/) by [mjm522](https://answers.ros.org/users/25029/mjm522/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-27**:
Are you sure both PCs are running the same software (versions)? Inexplicable `SEGFAULT`s (that's what `-11` errors are) can be caused by ABI incompatibilities. Perhaps one of the PCs is running newer/older versions of relevant packages.

**Comment by [mjm522](https://answers.ros.org/users/25029/mjm522/) on 2016-10-27**:
the files in my PC was copied from the files from the working PC.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-28**:
That doesn't guarantee it'll work.It could actually be the cause.

And "the files": which files are you referring to here: some parts of ROS proper, baxter sim pkgs, both, or something else?

**Comment by [mjm522](https://answers.ros.org/users/25029/mjm522/) on 2016-10-28**:
i mean all source files in the catkin_ws/src folder that relates to baxter simulator. I re-run cakin_make in mine, even I tried to directly downloading from the git again and recompiling it. Both didn't prove any good.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-28**:
Could be that there is actually just really something wrong with the code itself. I recommend reporting that to Rethink on the appropriate Baxter issue trackers.

Do please report back if you get this resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it had something to do with the urdf parser files. i reintalled all of those related ros packeages, and it started working. !!!

---

Originally posted by [mjm522](https://answers.ros.org/users/25029/mjm522/) with karma: 46 on 2016-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-28**:
Please just accept your own answer, as you really answered the question.

We don't really close questions here on ROS Answers. The 'green checkmark' is much more of a sign that a question is answered.